# Javascript Arrow Function multiple Inputs filtering an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrow-functions

I have an array of objects

```
[ { is_root: true, page_id: 20, has_children: true, url: "http://google.com", parent_page_id: 0},
  { is_root: false, page_id: 21, has_children: false, url: "http://google.com/2", parent_page_id: 20},
  { is_root: false, page_id: 28, has_children: true, url: "http://google.com/3", parent_page_id: 20},
  { is_root: false, page_id: 30, has_children: false, url: "http://google.com/3/1", parent_page_id: 28} ]
```

I want to build a menu structure. I need to get the first parent pages, and then loop through if each has children and sort the pages/subpages properly.

So the lambda I am trying to use is to filter the list down to pages that should be at the highest level of the structure. which means they stem off `is_root`, so I need the items in the array where the `parent_page_id` is equal to the `page_id` of the item in the array where `is_root = true`

this is what I have

```
 var parent = allItems.filter(x => 
     { 
         return x.parent_page_id == (y => y.is_root == true);
     });
 console.log(parent);
```

This syntax appears to work, but `parent` is an empty array. 
Here is the working fiddle. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e9yw9acf/)

My guess is `y` has no correlation to the original `allItems` array.

Comment: None of the objects in array meet condition described. `y` is not defined within `.filter()`

Comment: It sure looks like `parent_page_id` and `is_root` are properties on the same object. If that's the case, why don't you just use `x`? `return x.parent_page_id == x.is_root;`

Comment: This: `(y => y.is_root == true)` is a function, which will never be equal to a number. What exactly should the result look like? It sounds like for each root, you want a sub-loop. Or maybe for each `has_children`.

Comment: Are you trying to match up `x.parent_page_id` with `y.page_id` where `y.is_root == true`?

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: There will only be 1 root. It has a `page_id` I am trying to get an array of items where the `parent_page_id` is equal to the `page_id` of that root item. @

Comment: @squint yes this is what I'm going for. Once I have the children of `is_root` I can define the top level menu. Then I can build out all children of the top level menu, etc.

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm sorry but it is there. `so I need the items in the array where the parent_page_id is equal to the page_id of the item in the array where is_root = true`

Answer (score 1):

> so I need the items in the array where the parent_page_id is equal to the page_id of the item in the array where is_root = true

You're better off just finding the parent and then filtering.

```
var parent = allItems.find(x => x.is_root);

var directChildren = allItems.filter(x => x.parent_page_id == parent.page_id);
console.log(directChildren);
```